# Spirit Airlines: Carry-on weight limit?

Tags: airlines, hand-luggage, spirit-airlines

On their [website](https://www.spirit.com/OptionalServices), Spirit Airlines has clear size limitations of "personal items", carry-on and check-in luggage.

However, there does not seem to be a weight limit for carry-on luggage.

Does that mean Spirit accepts heavier bags (reasonable weight, around 10kg)?

Comment: Most of the airlines in the US don't have weight limits for carry-on bags, unless you've done something weird like fill you bag with lead, overloading the overhead bin capacity. Spirit is a low-cost carrier with lots of carefully enforced rules, but it wouldn't be that surprising for them to not have a weight limit in the US.

Comment: +1: I thought about the same question yesterday. You might also be interested in the weight limit for personal items.

Comment: That’s good news. I usually try to hang it casually over the shoulder to make it look lightweight. Worked so far - I hope it will also with Spirit (International flight to SouthAm)

Comment: They will, however, charge for oversize.  The page you cite doesn't say how much, but http://www.airline-baggage-fees.com/spirit-airlines.php says "Again, please pay attention to the size of your personal item! If you exceed the allowed dimensions, you may be charged up to $100 at the gate if your personal item is too big and is considered a 'carry-on' item."  And 18"x14"x8" is significantly smaller than the bag I typically carry on.

Comment: @WGroleau Of course you are absolutely right. Not that it were of public interest, but I asked the question because I purchased a carry-on add-on at the time of booking – which means I am allowed a carry-on bag and an additional personal item – and didn’t know whether I would have to buy the check luggage option, too. Thank you though for clearly stating this warning for other users, +1

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in observing that Spirit and many other airlines do not publish a specific weight limit for carry on bags.  Probably because this is a limit there's hasn't been a notable reason to enforce.  [Some exceptions are described here.](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/george-hobica/airlines-impose-weight-li_b_1281729.html)

The most specific practical limit you must comply with is any **limit of the overhead bin**.  I don't know what they generally are, but I've seen the stickers and some posts indicate 70-90 lbs.  The workaround for that is to put the bag under the seat in front of you.

10kg is not particularly heavy, but at the upper end of the above limits.  Note, while it will likely go unnoticed, if the crew does notice and thinks it might be to heavy to be safe, they will require you check it.  Once that decision is made, there is no point in arguing.  You only options are check the bag or depart the aircraft.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Since neither your answer, nor the linked reference resolve the question in its entirety, I will not accept your answer.

Comment: Just to clarify - you don't put items under *your* seat, but rather under the seat in front of you.  The space below your own seat is reserved for the passenger in the seat behind, since access is better from behind.  Passengers in the front row or at a bulkhead will generally be allowed to place these bags in overhead bins or in a closet.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Doh!  That's something feel free to edit yourself. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Indeed, this is common now among US carriers**. Since you have a size-limit, though, there will  be practical limit eventually. Given all the restrictions and additional rules for check-luggage, this is good for people to have flexibility.

10kg for a carry-on is very reasonable. *Most* airlines that do specify a weight limit usually put it at 22 lbs or 10kg. On very small planes I have seen lower limits down to 5kg when flying around Asia but that is fairly exceptional even and it causes problems because most of these airlines also have a rule about not putting valuable and electronics in checked luggage, so if you carry a couple of cameras, a few lenses and a laptop with power-brick, you are easily over 5kg or even 7kg.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since you’re concluding from other carriers to the one in question, the question is not answered and thus I will not accept your answer.

Comment: Sure I understand. It is stated by omission on the page you link and that is the soft of thing I see with other airlines. Although Delta specifically states there is no weight limit, they are the only ones I remember reading this.